# What is the minimum set of characters with which you can write any valid python program?

Tags: code-challenge, python

The proof of the set of characters is that there is a translator which takes any ascii python program as input and produces a limited character set version of the program. The limited character set program can be slower than the original program. It simply has to be possible to produce the same output as the valid python program.

For example, here is a translator that takes any ascii python program as input and writes out a version that doesn't use the character x:

```
import random
import string
with open('in.py') as infile:
    with open('out.py', 'w') as outfile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
        outfile.write("data = '")
        random_string = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(20))
        for line in lines:
            outfile.write(line.encode('string-escape').replace('x', random_string))
        outfile.write("'\n")
        outfile.write("exec data.replace('%s', chr(%s))" % (random_string, ord('x')))
```

note that this will fail if the program happens to have the random string in it already, but for the purposes of this question lets accept that 'any' can be slightly limited. We don't have to consider extremely low probabilities of failure due to random chance or a malicious input program.

Comment: The question is? No idea about the sense of this "questions"

Comment: good luck writing a _useful_ program without `sorted(set('import for while = in : if def [] return class () break .'))` On the other hand, you can write http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language) programs with only three characters.

Comment: @msw: To be fair, that's not true. All `for` loops can be replaced with `while` loops (though admittedly that doesn't get you anywhere if you leave in `def`, `import`, and `return`), all list literals could turn from `[...]` to `list((...))`, you can shuffle a program to avoid any `break`, and there are probably similar transformations.

Comment: @vishvanda: While this question has problems, it did inspire me to write such a translator, which removes all characters except for `"()+,.1[]cehijnorx`. My solution is [here](https://gist.github.com/3324382).

Comment: @msw: As you can see in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/3324382), it's actually possible to write any Python program with just the characters `"()+,.1[]cehijnorx`).

Comment: Interesting, amusing, and likely a fun puzzle. Cheers.

Comment: I thought it was pretty interesting, too bad it was closed as.

Comment: By the way, I've improved my solution to use only 9 characters: `()+1cehrx`.

Comment: But does it support unicode ;) Good explanation regarding codegolf, too.

Answer (score 17):

I've come up with a 9-character translator using `exec` (also posted at this GitHub [gist](https://gist.github.com/3324382)):

```
def convert_txt(txt):
    """Convert the text of a Python program to minimal Python"""
    s = "+".join(["chr(%s)" % "+".join(["1"] * ord(c))
                            for c in txt])
    return 'exec(%s)' % s
```

The only characters it needs are `()+1cehrx`.

Comment: LOOOOOOOOOOOOOL +1

Comment: Does Python permit literal `chr(0)` characters in strings?

Comment: That's not how it's used here. This creates a program whose string is like `exec(chr(1+1+1...)+chr(1+1...))`. The new program thus uses only 9 characters, reconstructs the string, and uses `exec`

Comment: Precisely. So if I pass it a Python program which contains a literal `chr(0)` it will break. The most obvious place in which a literal `chr(0)` would be valid is inside a string.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your original question. Anyway, I've been able to use it: for example, `chr(100) + chr(0)+chr(65)` yields `'d\x00A'`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood you yet again. Yes, it would lead to an error, as would a Unicode character.

Comment: You can support unicode and null characters if desired without extra characters by doing two translation steps:

the first to `exec(unichr(0+1+1+1+...)+...)` to remove all unicode and null characters and the second as above to remove 'uni0'

Comment: @paradigmsort Nice! Of course, that would cause the length of the code to expand by another ~2 orders of magnitude. Now that would just make it impractical...

Comment: **This has been beaten!** [8 chars](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11697/34718)

Comment: [Now in 7 chars](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110722/34718)