# Restricted-source, take this!

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

a.k.a. You Can Output Anything With Labyrinth Or Hexagony™

### Challenge

In a recent [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source) [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223439/78410), I could print any character with only half of the allowed digits with very small character count, [by abusing the "digit commands" and modulo-256 output function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223447/78410). Now, it's about time to make a general metagolfer for this kind of challenges.

For the sake of simplicity, we only consider Labyrinth programs of the form `<digits>.@`, i.e. construct a number, print it modulo 256 as character code, and halt. Also, the sequence of digits acts exactly like a number literal in this case.

Now let's assume we want to solve a [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source) challenge in the form of:

> Given the characters `.@` and a subset of `0-9`, print a character.

Given a subset of digits `D` and the target character `c`, find the **shortest** number `N` which will solve the hypothetical challenge above. In other words, `N` should satisfy the following:

- All the digits of `N` are in `D`.
- The Labyrinth program `N.@` prints the character `c`, i.e. `N % 256 == ord(c)`.

  - The byte value of `c` can be anything between 1 and 255 inclusive.
- Out of all possible `N`s satisfying the above, your program should output one that has the shortest length. If there are multiple possible answers, your program is free to output any of them.

You may take `c` as a character or an integer (charcode), and digits in `D` as integers or digit characters. Also, you may assume `D` is already sorted.

Assume the answer exists. Note that some conditions will lead to "no answer", e.g. only odd digits are allowed but you need to print an even character, or vice versa. You may assume that such conditions will never be given as input.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

The value of `c` is given as its character code.

```
D = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = 1 => N = 1
c = 57 => N = 313
c = 254 => N = 254
c = 100 => N = 1124 or 4452
c = 107 => N = 1131, 2155, 2411, or 3435

D = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8]
c = 58 => N = 826
c = 71 => N = 1111111
c = 255 => N = 26111

D = [7]
c = 49 => N = 777777
```

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

Expects `(D)(c)`, where `D` is a string of digits and `c` is an integer.

```javascript
D=>c=>eval(`for(;/[^${D}]/.test(c);)c+=256;c`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BasMwDIbveQpRdrBZ11S2FGcE95TzXmBsNLhJaQn1SEIvpc@eeetghlgHYaPP/vWdm2szuuH0Nb1c/KGdOzvXdufsrr02vdh3fhBV/v75dKvvH/lmasdJOFlJ92wVF5Xby7kGCytUmnhVZc5fRt@3m94fRSdqKRBASshzeAsYLudsorlGvSQU0z8RLomM7TbKQEXgByBilUJNjGpcg0Lm0AnDObzTpDnL/qSoKFNSXEZLl6pYEgZj7Uel1DhSK36YR7JJpdJr9Kf5rfkb)

Comment: ``D=>c=>eval(`for(;/[^${D}]/.test(c);)c+=256;c`)`` is only 46 bytes.

Comment: @Neil I was indeed trying to get rid of `k` but you're faster than me. Thank you. :-)

Comment: But recursive is shorter: [`D=>g=c=>eval(\`/[^${D}]/\`).test(c)?g(c+256):c`](https://tio.run/##bY/BasMwDIbveQpRdrDZ1lS2FGcb7i457wVKR4Kbho1Qjyb0MvrsqdcWZoh1EDb67F/fd3NqBnf8@hmfD37XTns7VXbdWWfX7anpRZ1vPh9@q/M2r@VybIdROPneCfeouJCvbqrAwgKVJl68Zc4fBt@3y953Yi8qKRBASshz@AgYzudsorlGPScU0z8RLomM1SrKQEXgj0DEKoWaGNX4BAqZQycM5/BOk@Ysu0tRUaakuIyWLlUxJwzG2rdKqXGkVvwxt2STSqWX6E9zrekC)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
Ɠ+⁹$Dḟ³Ɗ¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//xpMr4oG5JEThuJ/Cs8aKwr///zI1Nf9bMSwgMiwgNCwgNiwgOF0)

-1 byte thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)

Full program that takes `D` as the first argument and `c` in STDIN

### How it works

```
Ɠ+⁹$Dḟ³Ɗ¿ - Main link. Takes D on the left
Ɠ         - Read c from STDIN, set N = c
        ¿ - While:
       Ɗ  -   Condition:
    D     -     Digits of N
     ḟ³   -     Remove all elements of D
                This is an empty list (falsey) iff all digits of N are in D
   $      -   Body:
 +⁹       -     Add 256 to N
```

Comment: Here is a full-program version accepting the list as an argument and the ordinal from STDIN for [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//xpMr4oG5JEThuJ/Cs8aKwr///zI1Nf9bMSwgMiwgNCwgNiwgOF0).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh, nice!

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 59 bytes

```scala
d=>n=>Stream.from(1)find(x=>s"$x".forall(d.toSet)&x%256==n)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lcPKiy5sQPagQKn3XP67Kw)

Just a brute force solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes `D` as an array and `c` as an integer, in reverse order.

```
@ìkV}f@±X©G²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QOxrVn1mQLFYqUey&input=NTcKWzEgMiAzIDQgNV0)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
ＮθＷ⁻⪪Ｉθ¹⪪η¹≧⁺²⁵⁶θＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05qrPCMzJ1VBwzczr7RYI7ggJ7NEwzmxuAQop6NgCMQQoQwQR1NTwTexwLG4ODM9LygzPaNEIyCntFhHwcjUTEcBZFZAUWYeXLum9f//5oZchkYmZhb/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input of `N` and `D` as a string. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `N` as an integer.

```
Ｗ⁻⪪Ｉθ¹⪪η¹
```

Filter out the digits of `D` from the digits of `N`. While some remain, ...

```
≧⁺²⁵⁶θ
```

... add 256 to `N`.

```
Ｉθ
```

Output the final value of `N`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
πdµ∞╔▓|▒
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e364e6ecc9b27cb1&i=%5B1,2,3,4,5%5D,1%0A%5B1,2,3,4,5%5D,57%0A%5B1,2,3,4,5%5D,254%0A%5B1,2,3,4,5%5D,100%0A%5B1,2,3,4,5%5D,107%0A%5B1,+2,+4,+6,+8%5D,58%0A%5B1,+2,+4,+6,+8%5D,71%0A%5B1,+2,+4,+6,+8%5D,255%0A%5B7%5D,49&m=2)

### Explanation

```
WcEx-!CVB+
W          loop forever
 c         copy c
  E        get digits
   x       push D
    -      set difference
     !C    if empty, break out of the loop
       VB+ else add 256
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>29 24</sup> 22 bytes

```
(]256&+~0 e.e.~&":)^:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc67CsIwFAbgvU/x06G1qCE5uRroJDg5uauDpIiLb9BXj7FJl/TAWf6Pc/nElvUTRo8eB3D41EeG8@16ibs7adPtZ47AApu71g8P/4xDE17vLwTG1AQJBY0JIsdSyAq0zUJaVZKSsktQbYLz1eTmFLdNRkemmIKB@19z69hSldryJZmtkdZlq10qsU2xOsUf)

<sup>-2 thanks to Bubbler</sup>

Call it like: `1 2 3 4 5 f 57`, which returns 313.

- `]256&+~...^:_` Keep adding 256 while...
- `0 e.e.~&":` There is a digit of the right arg that's not in the left arg.

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zc67CsIwFAbgvU/x06G1qCE5uRroJDg5uauDpIiLb9BXj7FJl/TAWf6Pc/nElvUTRo8eB3D41EeG8@16ibs7adPtZ47AApu71g8P/4xDE17vLwTG1AQJBY0JIsdSyAq0zUJaVZKSsktQbYLz1eTmFLdNRkemmIKB@19z69hSldryJZmtkdZlq10qsU2xOsUf) using `&` trick on the inner `^:`.

Comment: Oh that's very nice.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>38</s></sup> 34 bytes

- -4 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor), for using `until`.

```hs
f d=until(all(`elem`d).show)(+256)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBDoIwEAXQfU8xiS7aOBpAKorUvYk3ICQQWoVYi4Ea4PSIxIW4fH/@nyJr7krrYbiCFC9jS00zrWmqtHqkkm2aomoZXXl8xwa6YOJKHllphKwIxBLzJFq3VS2baHm6KXspjSKglYVOFCqT03o80XoEyDCMz8Ym7NiLKcgJPOvSWNphj92iZwQ@z4fYRQ@36CNPwCW/4sGMHvdndh3nz9@@jzvcj/P9jIE7o8c5iYME/MMb)

Takes `d` as a list of `Chars` (i.e. a `String`) and `c` as an integer.

Comment: Your recursive function looks quite a bit like an `until`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##XcxBDoIwEAXQfU8xiS7aOBpAKorUvYk3ICQQWoVYi4Ea4PSIxIW4fH/@nyJr7krrYbiCFC9jS00zrWmqtHqkkm2aomoZXXl8xwa6YOJKHllphKwIxBLzJFq3VS2baHm6KXspjSKglYVOFCqT03o80XoEyDCMz8Ym7NiLKcgJPOvSWNphj92iZwQ@z4fYRQ@36CNPwCW/4sGMHvdndh3nz9@@jzvcj/P9jIE7o8c5iYME/MMb "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor indeed it does :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 36 bytes

```
"$<%'"~L$`.+$
/[^$&]/+`.+¶$$.($*257*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvqhGcoPNfScVGVV2pzkclQU9bhUs/Ok5FLVZfG8g5tE1FRU9DRcvI1Fzr/39DHUMjYxNTLlNzKMPI1ATKMjQwgLNgsqYWQIaJmQWXuSGUYWRqCmWZWOqYAwA) Takes `N` and `D` on separate lines but test suite splits on `,` for convenience. Explanation:

```
"$<%'"~`
```

Evaluate the following generated Retina program passing in only `N` as input.

```
L$`.+$
```

Use `D` to generate the Retina program.

```
/[^$&]/+`
```

The generated program repeats while `N` contains a digit not in `D`.

```
.+¶$$.($*257*
```

Each loop of the generated program adds `256` to `N`. This is a little unclear due to the quoting. The generated program looks like this:

```
/[^12468]/+`.+
$.(*_[256 more `_`s]
```

The `*_` converts `N` to unary. The 256 `_`s then effectively adds 256, after which the `$.(` converts the sum to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
f=lambda d,c:f(d,c+256)if{*str(c)}-{*d}else c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3hCoMgFIX/@xT@1LbFtKwW9DDNjAQzUWNE9OxOmezCveeDczjXHH7ZdBXCPKhxfU8jnO68n1G8N8oaLOezcN4ijq/HWUyXUE5AHuRqNuuhOxyIWzrhreC7dXLTSq7SI/KMg8FnkUpA0oNUO0htdo9w6YyKEQygsVJ7lL4l5RjjQGhVM0jAT1mbgbI6U2z@U3LrpoOsy9CSDJQx0ML69QU)

My first attempt at golfing in Python (or, for that matter, in an imperative language). Suggestions are welcome! Especially about conditionals, I don't really know all those `and` and `or` tricks, but I almost never see `if`-`else` used in Python codegolfing, so I guess I'm doing something wrong :).

Also, I had to increase the default recursion limit for some testcases, I hope that's ok.

Comment: Here, due to `f` needing a space before it if using the `and-or` trick, it actually does not save any bytes to apply that here. But in case you're interested, `a if b else c` is generally replaceable by `b and a or c` which saves up to a byte by default and maybe more or less depending on characters that need spaced. The notable exception is if `a` may be false.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes

```python
d,n=set(input()),ord(input())
while not set(str(n))<=d:n+=256
print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P0Unz7Y4tUQjM6@gtERDU1MnvygFzuEqz8jMSVXIyy9RAKkpLinSyNPUtLFNscrTtjUyNeMqKMrMKwGK/f8PAA) Simple brute-force solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 82 bytes

```python
f=lambda d,c,k=0:(all(_ in d for _ in str(k))and chr(k%256)==c)and k or f(d,c,k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxbCoAgEACvsgjBLvnRy6DAs4QpUmga5k@nt/BvGIa533zEMJZipVfXbhQYrrmT3YrKe9zgDGDAxgQVn5zQEalgQB8/NoOYSUpdjYM/s1gHbU/lTmfIaJH1wzgJxtnCiMoH)

Plain brute force, takes `D` as a string of the numbers and `c` as a character.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 68 bytes

```r
f=function(D,C)"if"(all((utf8ToInt(paste(C))-48)%in%D),C,f(D,C+256))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpBCoMwEEDRfY4hCDN0CiZkTCp0FTfd9wIiHQhIlDaeP9KKdOHu8fnvUuQuaxpznBP0FLCKUsEwTQBrFv@cHynDMnzyCwLi1XqsY6p7pEDy/S@GW8QioDsmjWoHu0OG7UHdNH/@hhE0GbLUkkdif0pOn5Jh3ptDsjdUqmw)

Fails in TIO for larger test-cases.

---

**without recursion:**

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 75 bytes

```r
function(D,C){while(T%%256-C|any(!(utf8ToInt(paste(+T))-48)%in%D))T=T+1;+T}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcqxCsIwEIDhvW/hELgjV2hCro1Kp3ZxzwuU0mBBUtEUEfXZI1iKQ7ePn/@WfJ38HPo4TgFaavD1OI@XAZwQmsu8eXfhCTuYo7duOoUI1@4eB5AOMTcWxRhEi@hqJ9VRuk/yoA5MCrMFXK3SbFaqovjzN/SgSJOhkiwS202q1CZp5qVVSGaPWZa@)