# FizzBuzz: Least unique bytes

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity

**Introduction:**

Although it seems challenges scored by least unique characters [have](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11690/encode-a-program-with-the-fewest-distinct-characters-possible) [been](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52655/generate-and-print-the-first-20-fibonacci-numbers-with-the-least-unique-characte) [attempted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34614/conways-game-of-life-with-smallest-set-of-source-characters), there are few which were well-received. I think it's a potentially interesting scoring criterion, as long as different languages aren't competing with each other (as with code golf).

**Challenge:**

Create a basic FizzBuzz program or function. The output should be the decimal numbers 1 to 100, inclusive. For multiples of three, print `Fizz` instead of the number, and for the multiples of five print `Buzz`. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five, print `FizzBuzz`.

A trailing newline is allowed, and `\n` or `\r\n` can be used to separate the numbers (and `Fizz`es and `Buzz`es and `FizzBuzz`es).

**Scoring:**

The answer (per language) with the least unique bytes wins. For example,

```
abbcccdeee
```

would have a score of 5, as it contains are 5 distinct bytes.

Comment: Is this really [Fewest (distinct) characters for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/fewest-distinct-characters-for-turing-completeness). Or are there plausible ways to implement FizzBuzz with fewer than needed to run a general program?

Comment: @xnor the equivalent of `print("1 2 3 Fizz 4 [...]")` for the extra esoteric languages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode a program with the fewest distinct characters possible,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11690/encode-a-program-with-the-fewest-distinct-characters-possible)

Answer (score 5):

## [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), score 1 (\$3.065... × 10^{185}\$ bytes)

<sup>I couldn't resist ;)</sup>

The program consists of 306542480187333548229216501998737670100823810347304444087725506753387994506955599380251625023427643514071322084229755566193943772995081070792874713832316221905650936799216302699728340431 times a single character of your own choosing, which translates to the following brainfuck program:

```
++>+++++>>>>>++++++++++[>+>>+>>+>+<<<[++++<-<]<,<,-<-<++<++++[<++>++++++>]++>>]>[+[[<<]<[>>]+++<[<.<.<..[>]]<<-[>>>[,>>[<]>[--.++<<]>]]+++++<[+[-----.++++<<]>>+..<-[>]]<[->>,>+>>>->->.>]<<]<[>+<<<,<->>>+]<]
```

Port of [*@MitchSchwartz*' brainfuck answer for the *1,2,Fizz,4,Buzz* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168511/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online as brainfuck.](https://tio.run/##PU7bCQMxDBvIjwmEFjH@6B0USqEfhc6fyjlaOQFHkWwd79vjdf@cz7XMaAMO7I@imH0MQA2FQMPhoUavrcLPbuyZ0SyrgoTFYQyFnMpiNxCiWa4LSSNSCnXde4b2iItNXx@0zDHJW0H6RGKokn1tmXiOmPCNXusL)

The byte-count is generated with [this 05AB1E program I wrote](https://tio.run/##jU7BSkQxDLz7FaXXND2LDPEsiBfxFIJUfKwPl32wW1n2sF@kJz9B7/7SM3nLenbSQjqdTGbatadxmOf8sGnbw1XK11lAXItavrl//fp4HPPd1FNbr6f98Jz6lHa9bXvaj/0ltST5@/3y5/NYLvLtsFm9tdWwmBAL/m1CZ5N5JhIKSID@oOLMcgiABgWGoaCwN/5aVDiPk1h4mCipwoUqwRAUNaqqmAHstGjxC5cyV1d4Z7Z4@B7neKFPH0K1xpDPKouUiCTsVcVOWyJeAUd4g/0C).

Comment: Is there a programming language whose empty program prints the fizz buzz challenge?

Comment: @RGS Not that I'm aware of. I know a program that loops infinitely, a few that print "Hello, World!", one that prints the 99 bottles of bear lyrics, but I haven't seen one (yet) that prints the FizzBuzz sequence.

Comment: I think you are winner, then xD

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 14 unique bytes (4552 bytes)

The characters I used are: `main(){}prtf+&`.

```c
a(i){if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}}n(i){if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}}f(i){if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)&printf(&i)){}}t(i){if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)&printf(&i)){}}r(){}p(i){if(r()&&printf(&i)){}if(++i){}}main(i){if(a(p(i))&n()){}if(a(p(p(i)))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(a(p(i))&a(p(i))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}if(f()&t()&n()){}if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}if(f()&t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(i))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(i))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p((i)))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p(p((i))))))&n()){}if(f()&t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p((i))))))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p((i)))))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p((i)))))))))))&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}if(f()&t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(i))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(i))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}if(f()&t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}if(f()&t()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(i))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}if(t()&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}if(f()&n()){}if(t()&n()){}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VbRisIwEPybskH8qFKIBO6KeIV7kP66OSNW02Qn2Y0o53GIgunMJLub2e2w3Q2D9z05c3SWNhvXvet3f3DjZKlzxhzneVRGtGbbP5CPl@X6l@XpGWe7ayYXZfq/KG9zMV4RG7woBzr/7q@35fyn4@QC8LN3S@/qKRBMN9IVEhYuS9GapQywgGLYRHVOzDSmAIlASHVKtwiBZAFZhLrtgR/nMQa1iYqU@Ow1HJsKSwLeOkOKKlxKy1U5e5ylp5z9hIsSYUU8dAGKBJARtmb38IAF4sciQ8TwNnukClWz8IQW66yOXPdQBg@fLGKIvGElVWLYsYKRU2KSOjogo2@AS@TYgxxObUZeROHKkkDZnjWm1qfJoaFhGZxwlDG8RyYcIyUcfJDZbup0Z6m7OR6YmWWCcIrWRPBclTBlk1am1Dx7QTlrnQAQGlsCVFP3hoqSpEkIJNq6Rc6stA2eoOgfSOCxV2WsqXiVLkuoWsvs/WmwH/3uy2@/fwA)

There is a lot of code here (so much that I actually had to add the `-w` flag to prevent exceeded debug output), so I will split the explanation into parts. Simply put, we are printing every character using brute force, since I originally thought that it would cost less bytes, but looking back it might actually have been a lot easier to use a logical method.

### Explanation

The first function `a(i)` takes in a digit `i`, and outputs that digit. We increment `i` 48 times, since the ASCII values for numbers are offset by `+48`, and then use the fact that `printf(&i)` acts the same as `putchar(i)` to print to STDOUT.

```c
a(i)
{
if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}
}
```

---

The second function `n(i)` prints a newline character `\n`. Later when we call this function, we won't actually input any parameter (it will be called by `n()`), which causes `i` to default to 0. Using this fact we essentially do the same thing as in the first function, except we increment by 10, since that is the ASCII value for `\n`.

```c
n(i)
{
if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}
}
```

---

The third function `f(i)` prints `Fizz`. There is not much to say, except we use the same strategy as in the first function, only we need to repeat this 4 times. It also helps that each ASCII value in `Fizz` is greater than the last, allowing us to simply increment `i` throughout the whole function, instead of using an extra character like `-` to decrement.

```c
f(i)
{
if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}
if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}
if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)&printf(&i)){}
}
```

---

The fourth function `t(i)` essentially does the same thing as `f(i)`, only it prints `Buzz` instead of `Fizz`.

```c
t(i)
{
if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}
if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)){}
if(++i&++i&++i&++i&++i&printf(&i)&printf(&i)){}
}
```

---

The fifth function `p(i)` along with a helper function `r()` returns `i+1`. I know that my function seems overly complicated for such a task, so let me explain. For some reason on TIO, simply using a function like `p(i){if(++i){}}` exploiting the return hack does not work. I suspect this is because the compiler optimizes the code by actually deleting it. Therefore the extra code you see is an attempt to trick the compiler into not deleting it.

```c
r(){}
p(i)
{
if(r()&&printf(&i)){}
if(++i){}
}
```

---

The final function `main()` will take all of the functions mentioned previously and combine them to print the FizzBuzz pattern for all 100 lines. Most of it is self-explanatory, except for how to print a number. A number is simply a concatenation of a bunch of digits, so we can use our function `a(i)` to print it. So if we want to print 12, we can do something like `if(a(1)&a(2)){}`. The problem is we don't want to use extra characters like `1` or `2`, which we can solve by repeatdly using the `p(i)` function. Since `p(i)` equals `i+1`, we know that `p(p(...i...))`, would equal `i` plus a constant, which depends on how many `p()`s we are nesting. So if we want to print `12`, we can do `if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(i)))){}`. The `i` variable here is declared as a main parameter, which defaults to 0.

```c
main(i)
{
if(a(p(i))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(i)))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(a(p(i))&a(p(i))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}
if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}
if(f()&t()&n()){}
if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(i))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(i)))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(i))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(i))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(i))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p((i)))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p(p((i))))))&n()){}
if(f()&t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p((i))))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p((i)))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p((i)))))))))))&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(i))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(i))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}
if(f()&t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(p(i))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&t()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(i))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(p(i)))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(i)))))&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))&n()){}
if(a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i))))))))))&a(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(p(i)))))))))&n()){}
if(f()&n()){}
if(t()&n()){}
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can achieve a score of 10 by doing the same as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201711/78410) and not using `-` (since there's no limit on source code length).

Comment: I've seen that method somewhere before. I think why I chose this method was because it was more conventional (and impressive). Although, it was definitely a bother to code out.

Answer (score 3):

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 1 unique byte

Another 1-byte solution. Unlike the other ones though, this one can actually be written down :P.

```
f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy82@v8/7f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 unique bytes

```
Do[Echo[If[Mod[d,1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1]<1,FizzBuzz,If[Mod[d,1+1+1]<1,Fizz,If[Mod[d,1+1+1+1+1]<1,Buzz,d]]]],{d,1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98lP9o1OSM/2jMt2jc/JTpFx1AbD4y1MdRxy6yqciqtqtJB1QKT0sE0CSQF1pESCwQ61QQsGTqwNvb///8A)

Comment: yes, I know... golfing just started!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen d is ok. it's in "Mod"

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 7 unique bytes

This uses [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110722/75323) to the "least amount of unique bytes for Turing completeness". I then encoded [this well-golfed Python 2 FizzBuzz answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58623/75323) and I got the program that follows.

```python
c="%c%%c%%%%c%%%%%%%%c"
ex=c==c
ee=c==""
exec"e=%x%%x"%ex%ex
exec"e%%%%%%%%=%x%%x%%%%x"%ee%ex%ee
exec"ee=%x%%x"%e%ee
exec"ee%%%%=%x%%x"%ex%e
exec"e=%x%%x"%ee%e
exec"ec=ex%cex"%e
exec"xe=ec%cec"%e
exec"xx=xe%cxe"%e
exec"xc=xx%cxx"%e
exec"ce=xc%cxc"%e
exec"cc=ce%cce"%e
exec"xee=ce%cec"%e
exec"cee=ce%cex%%cxe"%e%e
exec"exe=ce%cex%%cec%%%%cxe"%e%e%e
exec"xxe=ce%cxx"%e
exec"cxe=ce%cex%%cxx"%e%e
exec"ece=ce%cec%%cxx"%e%e
exec"cce=ce%cex%%cxe%%%%cxx"%e%e%e
exec"eex=ce%cec%%cxe%%%%cxx"%e%e%e
exec"xex=ce%cex%%cec%%%%cxe%%%%%%%%cxx"%e%e%e%e
exec"cex=ce%cxc"%e
exec"exx=ce%cex%%cxc"%e%e
exec"xxx=ce%cec%%cxc"%e%e
exec"cxx=ce%cex%%cec%%%%cxc"%e%e%e
exec"ecx=ce%cxe%%cxc"%e%e
exec"xcx=ce%cex%%cxe%%%%cxc"%e%e%e
exec"ccx=ce%cex%%cec%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%cxc"%e%e%e%e
exec"eec=ce%cex%%cxe%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%cxc"%e%e%e%e
exec"xec=cc%cec"%e
exec"cec=cc%cec%%cxe"%e%e
exec"exc=cc%cex%%cce"%e%e
exec"xxc=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"cxc=cc%cex%%cxe%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"ecc=cc%cec%%cxe%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"xcc=cc%cxx%%cce"%e%e
exec"ccc=cc%cex%%cxx%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"eeee=cc%cec%%cxx%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"xeee=cc%cxe%%cxx%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"ceee=cc%cec%%cxe%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e
exec"exee=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cxe%%%%%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e%e
exec"xxee=cc%cxc%%cce"%e%e
exec"cxee=cc%cec%%cxc%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"ecee=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cxc%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e
exec"xcee=cc%cxe%%cxc%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"ccee=cc%cex%%cxe%%%%cxc%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e
exec"eexe=cc%cec%%cxe%%%%cxc%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e
exec"xexe=cc%cxx%%cxc%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"cexe=cc%cec%%cxx%%%%cxc%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e
exec"exxe=cc%cec%%cxe%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%cxc%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e%e
exec"""x=""
"""
exec"x%c=c%%cxc%%xexe%%cxc%%xxc"%e
exec"x%c=c%%xee%%xee%%eex%%eeee"%e
exec"x%c=c%%exee%%ccc%%ceee%%xxe"%e
exec"x%c=c%%xxc%%xcc%%cxee%%xxe"%e
exec"x%c=c%%cxc%%eexe%%exc%%xeee"%e
exec"x%c=c%%xxe%%xxc%%cxe%%cxe"%e
exec"x%c=c%%ecc%%exee%%cxee%%ce"%e
exec"x%c=c%%xxc%%ce%%ccc%%ceee"%e
exec"x%c=c%%ce%%xxc%%xexe%%eex"%e
exec"x%c=c%%ecee%%xxee%%xeee%%ccc"%e
exec"x%c=c%%xcee%%xxe%%cxe%%cxe"%e
cx="""ccc
eec
cex
ccx
cxc
xexe
cxc
xxc
xee
xxee
cxee
ccc
ceee
xcee
ce
ccc
cee
cxx
xex
xxx
ece
exe
cec
ccc
cexe
cexe
exe
e
ccc
cee
xcx
xex
ecx
ece
exe
xec
ccee
cexe
cexe
exe
exee
cxee
cce
exxe
ccc
ccx
ccc
e
eec
exx
ccx
xee
ece
exx
cex
cex"""
exec"exec%cx"%ce
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVZJjttADLzrGQL0gbn3awoEcsrkkEPl9R4uvbAXO4YhS2QVWWTT3frz7@@v799frxfK/eCxb734zX0JC0rBJWK/txkEt5SHz8P7Eeq32horfHZnAHGMVMwgJtsgRcA1h3QTivohZgwLpQjUgmFhoTygDAsKlcXBghQqi4MFFCgLiWUVyxQazaS6IkEXxuSRaGIFDF0ByTIyi8zx0JKvHmDSEJk4ZRJbs04@Qtggk96@7B09Kg986pgwhXD7qDTnzx7wkBazeNRMsoUF98pnMnCIz1EWlrJEcGjmezwNj2Ummmmfieqx4JCpQclTZWKeFmRIVbZABFPmE4QVwk0CkOPzGF9s3HuCI4YNE8t1xGCOs3W5w9OfSbb@TNP5LJ8cI/3fqjRsxXNShHN3TyLwXjUxteK8qlPQPsMfWuEby9q7TyoagXyvYg7K/6sgP67g4H5akPumnR93O0N0Sy6t/ya73aY9pkJoR4RfxBpng7lCxN061bZYDueGoYdH1HCGuAJxMRK65BBGaqy61LsYDEVxPWtBlrxJaVmiN5IPvZamVhHdiWBbogaa5cLWwnYBPdhx6URcuneqFZelixt/kMsSXPALDGom2FM3qJfGU6i@C8AFqB3V7w8M6@Dodu4c3fA7h84RWUlJgT2xRjHFVoHXoGa3GCziMerSxvXXFtrLgjYS8nr9AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Lenguage, 1 distinct character

Now you see, the problem is that my program is *so large* that I kinda can't find a way to represent the byte count other than binary. So, uh, here is what I calculated my score as, represented in base 2:

```
110111000000000000000000000000110010000010000000010000000000010000000000000010000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011001111010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010010010010010010000000000100001001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001001001001100000000000000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010010010010010010010001100000011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011010010010010010010010100011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010010001001100000000011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010000100001011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010000000100001001011010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010001001001100000000000011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011010010010010010010010010010010010010010010010000000100001001011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011100
```

[BF used for conversion, but place a `[]` at the start of the program -- my browser is already lagging enough without me trying to open the large link again.](https://tio.run/##7VhbDoIwEDxQs3MCwkWMH2piYkz8MPH8qBWxj93S4gdr3I1CC9s6DmxnYH/dnS7H2@E8DG6MTe969/z472szbt@7af9pBK2wGbXjTtJLu1nfdUnQtvfhQK8DjxEg6sajvp0ffwQRgtn6MKa5uJPRpE0pEQAiD2CCkMCLJkgmH0cuQNAKcn2WwPMDnXB1XLZPKRQqY3WyUpT@HM0nzlXOCn9L8cWP2CgnwnU/cJ8EP2lL5oziFSWQSZQq0BZWgTK5uvTdB7xm5mliff37whqVR9Fz5olabSiD1ZzpYuJ4BeVSzb82PRtp9rESWllN@QHma5fQXFBgaYBSnyvhNb87Sxvy4oNYemioVFuQZdoUe18eL@pTzQOLxKJOlZlExa9i0ajFtvSKxMHVppoHrnzzrdv9ot73whzvN9SWvC5@xuXC/G0TANSpKMzTfsOrZjeLGt2EOdgqMgNiSrqapal1rylS864LaRMUM0s03xoHhuEO)

In other words, take any random character of your choosing and repeat it `n` times, where `n` is the binary number above converted to base 10. I may have accidentally miscalculated the byte count, but I know it's only 1 distinct character.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I thought a brainfuck program converted to Lenguage couldn't start with a `+`, since it's `000`. At the [Synthax section of the Lenguage esolangs page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage#Syntax) it states: "_First, the length of the program (in implementation-dependent characters) is calculated. Then, said length is converted to binary, left-padded by zeroes to a multiple of 3, and then evaluated like Binaryfuck._" So after you've converted the gigantic integer to binary and left-padded it with zeroes to a multiple of 3, it won't have those leading `+`/`000` anymore..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you're probably right. I couldn't find a proper generator so I tried to make my own, so it's probably flawed.