# What are some of the most character-efficient programming languages?

Tags: code-golf

Like Brainfuck or JSFuck would be efficient in terms of *number* of characters needed, but what languages would have the highest amount of information per character?

I was thinking of APL and J but there has to be more.

My goal with this question is to find a program that would allow a person with theoretically infinite amounts of computational power output through their fingers a program in the least amount of time possible.

Comment: I voted to close this as too broad, since I don't think a question like this is really on-topic anywhere on the stack exchange network. If you were able to provide a way to measure information you might have more luck on one of the other sites, like computer science. But please read their [help centre](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help) before you post! You may also find that asking for things like this in chat will work better, once you have enough reputation points.

Comment: Probably Jelly, but there’s no real way to objectively measure that, and it doesn’t always win everything—if there was one Objectively Most Efficient Language then this site would be a lot more boring. Also, if you really mean *characters* and not *bytes*, then... you could probably just get away with compressing Jelly into Unicode

Comment: This question will be closed because it is not a challenge. I would recommend asking questions like this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)!

Comment: You can find a list of all languages designed for code golf here: https://github.com/ETHproductions/golfing-langs . Of those listed, Jelly, 05AB1E, and Stax are top contenders, with many languages including Canvas and (my newly created language) Sledgehammer also winning sometimes.

Comment: Since this is a code-golf question, I feel like golfing the markdown sample answer given in the question anyway: Find a Turing-complete program allowing rapid development. (58 bytes)

Comment: RE: your edit - you are basically asking what programming language is best at winning challenges on this site. Seeing as different languages win different challenges, there would be no one correct answer. Usually, people do not care about runtime anyway, if they can save a byte or two.

Comment: do you mean characters or bytes? Most golfing languages on this site are judged by bytes, rather than characters.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61955/which-language-is-shortest)

Comment: You might be interested in language [golfing Elo ratings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8891/20260).