# Pangram "Hello, World!"

Tags: string, code-challenge, restricted-source, hello-world

*Your challenge*: The code must print "Hello, World!" and nothing else.

*Your restrictions*: Your program must satisfy these requirements:

1. The program must be a pangram.

   - It must use every character in printable ASCII, or, if you chose a particularly strange language, characters which are stored as one byte.
   - You are allowed to use other characters.
2. The program may not have unnecessary characters.

   - No subset of individual characters may be removed from the program while the program still outputs "Hello, World!"
   - For example, if code `ABBC` outputs `Hello, World!` then neither codes `AC` nor `BC` may output "Hello, World!", although code `BA` may.
   - This also means you cannot have a statement to print "Hello, World!" *per se* anywhere in your program, as everything other than that statement could be deleted and the program would do the same thing.
3. The program must not take input.
4. Your program does not create any errors.
5. You must not use any "Hello, World!" builtins.

*Your score*: Your score is calculated by [length of the program in characters] - [number of different characters]. Lowest score wins. (Tie-breakers are oldest post.)

*Nota Bene*: the second requirement is almost impossible to verify, so an answer is valid only after a week has passed for anyone who wishes to do so to be able to disprove the validity of your answer.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Interesting first challenge. For the `ABBC` example, would a more comprehensive list of restricted programs be `ABB`, `ABC`, `BBC`, `AB`, `BB`, `BC`, `AC`, `A`, `B`, and `C`?

Comment: @JoKing That is precisely correct.

Comment: Related: [Biggest Irreducible Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/196824/78410), which shares the "Hello World!" and irreducible code restriction.

Comment: If a language which supports a custom SBCS can also interpret the equivalent Unicode characters, would a submission in that language which contains only printable ASCII be valid?

Comment: @Unrelated "It must use every character in printable ASCII, or, if you chose a particularly strange language, characters which are stored as one byte." So I think not. EDIT: Yeah it's not, just as I thought.

Comment: @UnrelatedString No. The program must have every character in the SCBS. Also, if some characters in the printable ASCII are not in the SCBS, they need not be used. Just out of curiosity, what language are you using?

Comment: @Hyperbole I'm not really considering such an answer in Jelly, but Jelly is one such language where by default programs are read in the SBCS but an interpreter flag allows it to use UTF-8 (silently ignoring codepoints with no equivalent).

Comment: If our language cannot represent strings, may we output the next best thing?

Comment: Given that this is still fairly new, I’d suggest changing the string to something like `Greetings, World!` to avoid Hello World builtins

Comment: Next time, maybe try the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges).

Comment: @user, if it's numbers, no.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/112827)

Comment: I want to make an edit to the challenge prohibiting testing for the length of the string, but something tells me that this is a bad idea. Thoughts?

Comment: @Hyperbole That's an [unobservable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/79857), I'd recommend against it.

Comment: So bad that I cannot find an esolang who encode its n'th program as n'th permutation of all printable ascii. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 256 bytes, 256 characters, score=0

```
m←`C₁†ȯ→*2c¨abqnpsyhkzjwf
¢"H½↕↑↓↔∟¦¡¿‼…‰‡√≤≥±∂∫∞≈≠≡⌐¬÷×τ►#$%&'()+Φ-./013456789:;<=>?@ABDEFG¤IJKLMNOPQRSTUVṄXYZ[\]^_⁵ı§χituvxg¹{|}~·₀₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉⌈⌉⌊⌋ΓΔΘΛΞΠΣ€ΨΩαβγδεζηθλμξπρςσ▲φƒψω⁰r²³⁴d⁶⁷⁸⁹£,¥o´ ▼!◄lȦḂĊḊĖḞĠḢİĿṀWȮṖṘṠṪẆẊẎŻȧḃċḋėḟġḣeȷŀṁṅṗṙṡṫẇẋẏżÄËÏÖÜŸØäëïöüÿø◊□¶«»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcTXchJRHAfge5/C3nvvvffejV2jscfYdXYPZLMLjIlJXLAMYQMhUTIGCIE9C8rMOYvD1dln@P9eBP0uvvauzo5W6yGMvmu7wHRoqeYEjP6FK2@Kses3nj560vm6vePN/Zd3ponhmfvFbxifYXyCMQBjEOaQyApH1KHVoGWh5aE5ML/CysAaEQWYDGYOZhKWCSsFy0GsT4zLiowHYdjerNlz5s6bv2CRyi5Zumz5ilWr16xdt37Dxk2bt2zdtn3Hzt179u4TmQMHDx0@cvTY8RMnT50@c5Z4@PyFi5cuX2m7Cn3KL4jRoOfe864Xr@4K/vbd@w@iAqaBMbAQWBisG8wA6wEzwSzETMT@H0EsqgbUoEqobyqpUioNNq7G1A9VUEU1qUpqSpVVRbmqqmrqT6AFesCCEOxiYPztD8zAgp5/JopiEnrpFvQy9Ap0FzoX6cVi5LEoTYddm4F4@EEzSy7zI@RGfJvcpJ8id9jP@3Xi2rnmL@I28QTxFPGf5BnkRcj72Kg2R8kN@VFyo36c3CHfITd9u1lpaMR14t3E48S/EHeI58jrIS9KXm@jJsMyKnulLb83XJmQGZmTE7Isa7IuXcQjsB1RFjlRbbX@AQ)

I *think* this is irreducible.  It certainly took a bit of effort to build, but striving for a score of zero is inviting pretty close scrutiny...

[Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) has 256 characters on its [codepage](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage), so this pangram needs to use all of them.  Aiming for a zero score also means that (a) the 'program' code cannot easily include any of the letters of 'Hello, World!', and (b) we need to find a way to 'recycle' the letters 'l' and 'o', which each occur more-than-once in the output.
Unfortunately, [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) uses '!' as its indexing function, which rules-out the most straightforward approach to extracting elements from a long string, so we need to find a different way to do this.

Here's my approach:

**line 2: the encoding string (228 characters, + 2 characters `¢"`)**

```
¢"H½↕↑↓↔∟¦¡¿ ... öüÿø◊□¶«»      # A 228-character string, repeated forever.  
                                # Since one of the characters is a '\', though,
                                # this is read by Husk as a 227-character array.
                                # The characters of 'Hello, World!' are inserted
                                # at specific positions in the infinite string, 
                                # (so they occur out-of-order in the single copy).
```

**line 1: the indexing program (26 characters)**

```
     †ȯ   c¨abqnpsyhkzjwf       # For all the codepoints of the index string "abqnpsyhkzjwf":
        *2                      # double them
       →                        # and add 1.
  `C₁                           # Now divide the encoding string into substrings with these lengths
m←                              # and get the first letter of each.
```

The indexing string `"abqnpsyhkzjwf"` is constructed to 'hit' the letters 'o' and 'l' 2 and 3 times, respectively, by 'wrapping around' in the infinite list, so that those letters only need to occur once in the encoding string.  The largest index needs to be the same as the length of the encoding string, in order to 'hit' the same target ('l') twice in a row: this is achieved with 'q' (2x codepoint 113 + 1 = 227).

Comment: @Razetime - Yeah, but this isn’t code golf, so I need to use all 256 characters, right...?

Comment: hmm yeah (silly me)

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>111</s>  109 bytes, score = 14

```c
main(){printf("H%cllo, Wo\x72ld!",39+sizeof"14568:<=>?@ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ[]`bghjkquvwy0|~#$&'*-./^_");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ8lDNTknJ19HITw/psLcKCdFUUnH2FK7OLMqNT9NydDE1MzCysbWzt7B0cnZxdXN3dPL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsIjIqOjYhKT0jK7uwtKy80qCmTllFTV1LV08/Ll5J07r2//9/yWk5ienF/3XLAQ)

Edit: bugfix thanks to Noodle9

Edit 2: changed order of numbers and operators in the string to fix a problem found by G B, replaced `"Hello, World!"` with `"Hello, Wo\x72ld!"`

### shorter solution based on Sheik Yerboutis Code (107 bytes, score = 12)

```c
main(){printf("H%cllo, Wo\x72ld!","_:?=<#$&*-+^|./4138596@ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ`bghjkquvwysz0~e"['>']);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ8lDNTknJ19HITw/psLcKCdFUUlHKd7K3tZGWUVNS1c7rkZP38TQ2MLU0szB0cnZxdXN3dPL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsIjIqISk9Iyu7sLSsvLK4yqAuVSla3U49VtO69v//f8lpOYnpxf91ywE)

Comment: @Noodle9 thanks, it should be fixed now

Comment: [-5 characters](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ8lDNTknJ19HITy/KCdFUUlHSVlFTV1LV0/fwNDI2NTcwtLKxtbO3sHRydnF1c3d08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCwiMiouPiEpPSMru7C0rLyisqYuprgqVSnazCRW07r2//9/yWk5ienF/3XLAQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sheik Yerbouti I dont' think, that that solution is allowed. You can remove letters from the string and numbers from the index at the same time. [example](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19fPzcxM09Ds7qgKDOvJE1DyUM1OScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSUdJWUVNXUtXT9/A0MjY1NzC0srG1s7ewdHJ2cXVzd3Ty9vH188/IDAoOCQ0LCIyKi4@ISk9Iyu7sLSsvKKypi6muCpVKdrMJFbTupaLCKv0garBiv///5eclpOYXvxftxwA)

Comment: @xibu oh you are right! I fixed it at the cost of one character [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ8lDNTknJ19HITy/KCdFUUlHSVlFTUtXT9/A0MjYxNTM3MLSysbWzt7RydnF1c3d08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCwiMiouPiEpPSMru7C0rLyisqYuprgqVSla3UE9VtO69v//f8lpOYnpxf91ywE "C (gcc) – Try It Online") Anyway, your `sizeof` approach is different enough from this shorter code to be posted alongside with it.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti I've found a view problems with your implementation, [this](https://tio.run/##tY/HWsJAFEbX@hTXWCYRYgiEpqJg772LJU4mYXSYwWRCFMujGwPixg1s3N3vLs45P9Y9jOO4aVOuam8tn3LpqsrGJGZMpOFc@MwZU9LK@MTUtD5jmOVioWRlc/nZ@crCYnVpeWV1bX1za3tnd2//4PDo@OT07OLy6vbu/sFrPD49h@3o5fX9s14POqkMUa5RDd1ocx@xYQzpy5jZnJUvFEvlnrA2rDDodG3Vnm3EMED41KPcZqCiFIImDQLKPW30vzv@ZjiEEZmYAdUROIIEHEnADZt7BEQoW6EcnJQxrXwf1z2hUgFEEFAOAstkIRfSllTwwSTT6g7qs9Qkw9fg5/cLdUICUoBoE99lIoq/sMtsL4j16Bs) should fix them (explanation in the footer). It is still shorter than my solution using sizeof.

Comment: @xibu yes I forgot to add `+` to the string anyway the code should be 108 characters, you don't need two backslashes

Comment: Still not ok: `main(){printf("H%cllo, World!",79|35);}`

Comment: @GB that gives Hollo, World.
But it can still be reduced to: `0145`, `0146^3` and `-0147^~3`

Comment: You are right, I didn't check the output and assumed I had to produce 111 as result (instead of 101). However, my point still stands: as long as there are [numbers][operators][numbers] in the source code, a lot of combinations are possible.

Comment: @GB oh, I missed that. Should be fixed now. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/),  <s>119</s>  112 bytes / score 17

```ruby
puts ["%x"%(("!\#&+,-01245:;<>?@ABDEFIJKLNOQRUVWXYZ`dflqnry{|}"=~/$/)^"s8j9bePwGp7SgMTCvznH".to_i(36))].pack'h*'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFghWkm1QklVQ0NJMUZZTVtH18DQyMTUytrGzt7B0cnF1c3Ty9vHzz8wKDQsPCIyKiElLacwr6iyuqZWybZOX0VfM06p2CLLMik1oNy9wDw43TfEuawqz0NJryQ/PlPD2ExTM1avIDE5Wz1DS/3/fwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 101 bytes, 101 - 95 = 6

```python
print('o#$%&*./0W368;<=>? @ABCDEFG,IJKLMNOPoQRSTUVXY\154Z^_`abcflghjkmqsuevwyz{|}~H'[::-9]+"\x72ld!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSfXpSYq2CrUKSkpATkZuaVaKjnK6uoqmnp6RuEG5tZWNvY2tkrODg6Obu4urnreHp5@/j6@QfkBwYFh4SGRUTGGJqaRMXFJyQmJaflpGdkZecWFpemlpVXVlXX1NZ5qEdbWelaxmorxVSYG@WkKCpp/gfapFdcUpRZoKHJlVqRmqwBdYUmV1p@kUKyQmaeQlFiXnqqhkGFkYGOgkGFeZqmFZeCQmaaQnJGkUaypkJefglIFVQfSE5BAeJ2iALN/wA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 100 - 95 = 5

```python
M#$%&"()*+H-./0e1234l5678l9:;<o=>?@,ABCD FGIJWKLNOoPQRSrTUVXlYZ[\c^_`b"dfgh]ikmn'pqst!uvwxryz{}a|~jE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVh7d9M2FP@7@RRqSrHdxE1c9sJrC4Xx6AaUDTa2hRAcR00Ejmxkp014ffXuSrIsWXHKWc9JY@v@7tXVfSvZqpil9NbVzjbqLXLWGxPay@Raq0XmWcoKlK9y9cgiOknnrVacRHmOXhRR/N71wtbWBJ@j0YhQUoxGbo6Tc764xR/2cw5CR2gwbElclmYawnCxYBRp5D4ne4icG2sIJzlGfcW/yGdCQBfRxTwXYgBerDLsigVEcpSQvOCErfOUcRgiVKBDc6soyzCdcCYPoHyTDeTca6kz3wPKDKwwOqUFZhnoj1mzCbooTidYG2IegQ5giNJqajktZpgZy2o9SwnfASh9tcTlwTv/UksfFmnB1x5GoL1anBDOFmgP4Azeb6l3vIxxnt@fRRz1LKWaD48XU1sYw1OwJa6w8qTposgWxRnF2pUpIErNM3E8cIofoEOUwqe/DII@/IU8mkCjCQjYv2SkwG48Y27qWR7AjKXMbb9kBE9QkaKMgTXAiRdRQiYI/i8wcncnHopyFMNJohhUfE3bu6lX0/AkSbSGlzOSYFQ5Q7q53FAfiGsiRRQEPCK5yT7sQqf4ufSKS4RV9wi3dVcaTG1cB1aB2kX4IgETvWQLIyiUlztHHAOr8QyLdOGwSmWxKMJZkZWLtlSiKEHHRyjB1K3iRWy1FlJ1CPKRWwP4FoAjDrQcGV@@ehYES2/wpa0ZBEGjLr75/r82gR3ApmF9G7@MQuDZq8J/U@kwgkHQZK5bZQqZRUpiRYRL3BQXPJV0lKlz6zSTnlPpoddbW9dkpEiGilEmDWzNcDRxA08RUjZxY1EuY1kl/UBX1Vir@GwxH2NDyWVZV2R8LdH2Ec9VqGuIp@PSQzTl6YacfnBw67vvf/jxp9uO0GYFjEv@sFTnUQYoUx7WuazKakIhCmBwjyuFe60N7Bu1adKEy6R7QR91LNHNstcNvZQKc8aVx7V2fCdEXKxPtRFpaUS2oNp8lTN5egzM@BsaESDqqdBVlC8jofSag5y9eiVw3jiexaOrlU0R3cMgEQpVTLlCd4iwLBWxOGbbCVFj9zArsE4KGWNCPHx20BOo2gw4WmWWx5Z7onEMBlN7CBHr1H1CJ3hZyi3FNOpW5rqGtJ12WGWOKNFe9Vrpu8E5nizucAjRbtE8oiRbJFFBUlrX42ulf9nNDNqN2tkGGtY1WIYWU7iJabh3YEFvOqFZ2qsOvC2Lg1lFVUGrQJ4m2p17yygqa4hNZ2VOaHdMhdYrgzD0g2GdMamdt@onRihbO7k1BiO6hVYW2FPgElKxNIGX5hm6qDZ26ZeuxqgguZ/SgqUJepikl3WRh0pk2aaCOvm4TraonxS1Pir4gaX3l2acDXvjVGMrDHqdte2e2vSDOv2iRvfX@F/ZdIv/TrOa8q4AiymJsTvwg24wtD3zztGpXB947Ul2q2GHjQ7PQaNv8uypHSzmu07Vu1RdFMFwDw4Uzwid1uGjTc5EegDiNxrRnW3XfbbCqHpu4DUmIUPCdi1reF/gnduwjLXjkzW8sc/hNYyPrmM8vobxwXWMR0c2p7D1CdwMZnMM1b3eZPZ6ux1fxkzUHdfKVrdewnS365XBIJq20@s54gXIESf36xeOk6LA86yQl44JuSBw4xqv0EfM0rbVZjDcQty8YO7Y68Qd/hCtnX2wXtOEgmupPtwA7ASVTU7P6ixknaWadyzpqdN4yzEQp43CyqnRFnfmNFzjuAE2B8Fr6oRybLEIj536fK2vbZ4YAFUKGiwzg@VbWhgy9EgnRgo51Um3yyvBHEbDaAo3Jh4upWSgl5JLKkybbbhnilMsScGLcStj6ZRFcwivdrt99XTnxu7NNtSXzmN/v9fHfPJJ@OiT3A5/PkyPju/c7Z7cu/8Levjo9NdXvz15dpY@//2PF@zln3/9nfzz7@B1/Gb0dtyenE9nQ/J@Tp3sQ15sLy4ul2z18dOX6PPXdw@uYKNBIJpui/DfHWg0x6ORGI9GI97CRiM@JRHQqfEXi1JlOAaw84pRLogLjEqG5@W54ohyyBgjnhsrfvgdUv1aIAc0ObqTfT4mgwVJOZld/Qc)

Note that the version on TIO is missing a couple of instructions (notably `'`), so I've copied the interpreter here. This program works because Backhand executes every fifth instruction thanks to the first `M` (it's actually a little more complex than this), so the actual code is more like:

```python
M    "    H    e    l    l    o    ,         W    o    r    l    c    "    ]    '    !    r    a   j
```

However, since you can't remove the spaces inbetween without breaking the flow of the program, you can replace them with whatever you want. The final check is that the `j` jumps to the 10th character (`H`) to halt and output,, which is less feasible if you modify the program. It's possible you might be able to form a valid program from this mishmash, but it is unlikely, and I'm sure that there's another permutation that fixes that.

#### Explanation:

```python
M                      Increase the step count from 3 to 5
 "Hello, Worlc"        Push the string to the stack
               ]       Increment c to d
                '!     Push !
                  r    Reverse the stack
                   aj  Jump back to the 10th character
  H                    Halt and output the stack
```

Comment: you can remove the `~` then it goes 2 back and 1 forth, and return still return to 10th position

Comment: @Alexbries ah right, should have been more careful with placing that `}`s. Fixed

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), score <s>30</s> 124 - 95 = 29

```js
alert(`Hell`+String.fromCharCode(057^"#$%&*-/1234689:;<=>?@ABDEFGIJKLMNOPQRTUVXYZ][_bcjkpqsuvwxyz{|}~\\".length)+', World!')
```

The `o`s of `fromCharCode` cannot be put inside quotes. Its char code is 111, which can't be uses directly as an argument to `String.fromCharCode`. You can't XOR to get it because you need 64, 86, 104 or 106, which are also impossible, I think.

Comment: Aren't there 95 printable ASCIIs?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Sorry, I have a headache, I just copied some number I saw without thinking too hard about it...

Comment: @Alexbries Your version still outputs `Hello, World!` if you remove the leading `!`.

Comment: I just noticed that it can be reduced to these 2 [variants](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@Yk1pUYpucn1ecn5Oql5OfDhHRSPBITdAOLinKzEvXSyvKz3XOSCxyBmrQMDA0NdHUVs/J11EIzy/KSVFU1@QirMUszghN0///AA), but you can fix it by simply moving the 5 before the 1

Comment: @Alexbries I just managed to golf a byte off using `^`, I think it's safe from your variants this time...

Comment: @tsh I switched to `o` as it has fewer factors, does that help?

Comment: Maybe you can move all `xX%&*-|<=>~` to the end of string to make sure only digits concatenation will happened. It may be more reliable.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <sup><strike>118</strike></sup> <sup><strike>117</strike></sup> 116 - 95 = 21

shoutout to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh) for spotting 2 issues

```javascript
alert(`Hello, Wo${('\71'+";#%&*/8025:<=>[]?@ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRTUVXYZ|_bcfjkpmqsuvwxyz".length^-~94).toString(36)}d!`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@Yk1pUYpucn1ecn5Oql5OfDhHRSPBIzcnJ11EIz1ep1lCPMTdU11ayVlZV09K3MDAytbKxtYuOtXdwdHJ2cXVz9/Ty9vH18w8IDAoJDYuIjKqJT0pOy8ouyC0sLi0rr6isUtLLSc1LL8mI062zNNHUK8kPLinKzEvXMDbTrE1RTND8/x8A)

Comment: Maybe [remove the `\\`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@Yk1pUYpucn1ecn5Oql5OfDhHRSPBIVanWUFJWVdPSNzAysTC1sraxtbN3cHRycXVz9/Ty9vH18w8IDAoJDYuIjIqNjotPSs7KLigsLi0rr6isqqlT0stJzUsvydA2tNRWN1fXNdDUK8kPLinKzEvXMDbTrM3XUQjPL8pJUUzQ/P8fAA)

Comment: @tsh but then i don't have all the ascii pritable characters

Comment: I mean this program may still print "Hello, World!" without the `\\` in it. So it does not follow the rule of "may not have unnecessary characters"

Comment: `${...length...}` -> `l`

Answer (score 4):

## [BASIC](http://www.yabasic.de), 129 bytes

```
FOR i=8-2 TO 79 STEP 3+3:PRINT MID$("9*./!H065<>e?@ABClGJKLQlUVYZ[o\]^_`,abcf  ghjksWmnpqxotuvwyrz4{|}l~#%&'d",MOD(i,73),1);:NEXT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/380/SCHT1kLXSCHEX8HcUiE4xDVAwVjb2CogyNMvRMHX00VFQ8lSS09f0cPAzNTGLtXewdHJOcfdy9snMCc0LDIqOj8mNi4@QScxKTlNQSE9Iyu7ODw3r6CwIr@ktKy8sqjKpLqmNqdOWVVNPUVJx9ffRSNTx9xYU8dQ09rKzzUi5P9/AA)

Updated to a valid version thanks to Dominic van Essen.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I've deleted 5 characters (+3#%&) and it still works... [try it](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/380/SCHT1kwhxF/B3ELXUiE4xDVAwdQqIMjTL0TB19NFRUNJXUtP38DDyMTGLtXewdEpx9ndyzvHJzA0LD8yKjpGJzYuPkEhMSk5LTw9Iys7PzevoLCouKS0LKe8orIqpbqmtk5RSSdTx1DT2srPNSLk/38A)...

Comment: ...and deleting significantly more characters also works, too... [try it](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/PyDI0y9EQckjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VR6f9/AA)...

Comment: Something like [this](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/380/SCHT1kLXSCHEX8HcUiE4xDVAwVjb2CogyNMvRMHX00VFQ8lSS09f0cPAzNTGLtXewdHJOcfdy9snMCc0LDIqOj8mNi4@QScxKTlNQSE9Iyu7ODw3r6CwIr@ktKy8sqjKpLqmNqdOWVVNPUVJx9ffRSNTx9xYU8dQ09rKzzUi5P9/AA) might be golfable, though...?

Comment: @Dominic van Essen - Ahhhhh.... guess I'm not as smart as I thought I was. Haha delete one character it stops working, delete almost the whole thing and it works fine. Hmmm. I'll look at your example.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I am removing this answer as per our [policy for handling invalid submissions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/68942). Feel free to edit to a valid solution and flag for undeletion.

Comment: [Unfortunately](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/PyDI0y9EQckjNScnX0chPL8oJ0Xp/38A)
,don't worry we got face slaped like this too

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>119</s> 117 bytes, score=<s>24</s> 22

Thanks to Dominic van Essen for spotting a bug.

```r
cat('Hello, Wo',intToUtf8(nchar("#$%&*-./012479:;<>?@ABDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSVXYZ[]^_`bgjkmquvwyz{|}~")+53),"\x6Cd!",sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREPdIzUnJ19HITxfXSczryQkP7QkzUIjLzkjsUhDSVlFVU1LV0/fwNDIxNzSytrGzt7B0cnF1c3d08vbx9fPPyAwKDgsIjIqOjYuPiEpPSs7t7C0rLyyqrqmtk5JU9vUWFNHKabCzDlFUUmnOLXAVklJ8/9/AA)

Uses the [hex code trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191117/86301) to encode the last `l` as `\x6C`. This saves 2 bytes: 1 by avoiding the reuse of the `l` (none of the other characters are used anywhere else), and 1 by avoiding having to escape the `\` (as `\\`) in the string.

The long string in the middle is 61 characters long. They are all necessary to get the character `r` (ASCII code 114), which is produced by the `intToUtf8(nchar("...")+53)` part.

Comment: I deleted some characters: [try it](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREPJQ0lHPTUnJ19HITy/KCdFUV2nOLXAVklJ8/9/AA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen argh, how did I miss that? Fixed now (I hope).

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), score 114 - 95 = 19

Saved 2 bytes and removed 3 points thanks to [Sheik Yerbouti](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100356/sheik-yerbouti)!!!

```c
j;main(){for(;j<74;j+=6)putchar("H#$%&'e*-./0l12358l9:>?@oABCDE,FGIJK LMNOPWQRSTUoVXYZ\\r^_`bglkqsvwdxyz|~!"[j]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/LOjcxM09Dszotv0jDOsvG3MQ6S9vWTLOgtCQ5I7FIQ8lDWUVVTT1VS1dP3yDH0MjY1CLH0srO3iHf0cnZxVXHzd3Ty1vBx9fPPyA8MCg4JDQ/LCIyKiamKC4@ISk9J7uwuKw8paKyqqZOUSk6K1bTuvb//3/JaTmJ6cX/dcsB)

All characters outside of the double-quotes are needed in order for the program to compile and run properly. Taking any of the characters out from the double-quoted string will mess-up `Hello, World!` from being printed properly. That string is *exactly* `Hello, World!` with 5 characters in between each character.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI0uzOi2/SMM6y8bcxDpL29ZMs6C0JDkjsUhDKctDWUVVTT1VS1dP3zDHyNjUwjLHys7ewTHfydnF1U3H3dPL20fB188/IDA8KDgkNCw/IjIqJiauKD4hKT07p7C4rLwipbKqps5aUSk6K1bTuvb//3/JaTmJ6cX/dcsB "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @SheikYerbouti Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), score \$ 116 - 108 = 8 \$

```
1=`wc -m<<<'␀␁␂␃␄␅␆␇␈␎␏ABCDEFGIJKMNOPQRSTUVXYZabfghjkqsuvxyz234567890_+[];:~./>?\|"%^&*'`
print   He${(L#)@}lo, World!
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwbrk_JRUWxUNGxt1Vz8X9aWlJWm6FjdLDG0TypMVdHNtgOIMjEzMLKxs7Bx8_I5Ozi6ubu6eXt6-fv4BgUHBIaFhEZFRiUlp6RlZ2YXFpWUVlVVGxiamZuYWlgbx2tGx1lZ1evp29jE1SqpxalrqCVwFRZl5JZweqSrVGj7Kmg61Ofk6CuH5RTkpilC75wHdwaXJVVJZkFqcWqKgmxiqUJqXWViaygWhbDWAWouVlDRBLq_V5CpILE7OzLTVqFbU06sD8lOTM_IVcjOLizPz0q0UVKoh8lY1EN21EPni5PyiVKCsMsgQBV0gAyKtYKugEo0hGsuVWpaYo6ACEoa4csECCA0A)

`␀␁␂␃␄␅␆␇␈␎␏` should be the unprintable characters `0x00` to `0x08` and `0x0E` to `0x0F`, but these don't render in SE markdown.