# Writing erasable code

Tags: string, code-challenge, source-layout

My phone number (which I will not be sharing here) has a neat property where there is a two digit number, which when iteratively removed from my phone number will eventually remove all the digits.  For example if my phone number were

```
abaababbab
```

Then by repeatedly removing `ab` we would eventually get nothing (I encluse the string I am removing in brackets to make it clear)

```
abaababb[ab]
abaab[ab]b
aba[ab]b
ab[ab]
[ab]
```

Now to generalize this property lets have any string.  A "minimal eraser" of that string will be the smallest substring such that if iteratively removed it will eventually make the string empty.

Some examples at the bottom.

## Task and Scoring

*Warning: This challenge is not [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).  Do not assume it is without reading the scoring*

Your challenge will be to take a string as input and output a minimal eraser of that string.

Your answers will be scored by taking them as a string of bytes and calculating that string's minimal eraser.  The length in bytes of that eraser is your score, with lower being better.

Your answer must support strings containing all printable ascii plus any characters that appear in your program.

## Test cases

```
abaababbab -> ab
baababbab -> baababbab
baababab -> baababab
echoecho -> echo
ototoo -> oto
ibiibibii -> ibi
aabaabaa -> abaa / aaba
```

Comment: Suggested test case: `aabaabaa` -> `abaa` or `aaba`.

Comment: I'm thinking of how one might score well without golfing the actual task. I'd want a language with a char that ignores the next char including another of itself, and also a no-op char. Anyone got one?  Call `_` the ignore-next and `n` the no-op. Make an eraser string `_n_a_b_c` where `a,b,c` are [minimal distinct chars needed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11690/encode-a-program-with-the-fewest-distinct-characters-possible). By inserting into itself as `_n_a__?_a_b_cb_c`, we can reduce to just `b`, and likewise any chars. This lets us make any program be erased by this string.

Comment: @xnor Well lenguage can score 1 on this challenge, if you are looking for a language. And I would think that glypho could probably score pretty low too, maybe 2 or 3.  But as for your schema I think klein should fit the bill with `!` as the skip and `.` as the noop.

Comment: In `ototoo` if you start by removing the first instance, it doesn't work.  do we assume we always remove the last instance, and then repeat?  or do we have to try every possibility, and call it an "eraser" if any of them work?

Comment: @Jonah `ibiibibii` doesn't work if you remove only the last one.  It is an eraser if there is any way to do it.

Comment: Do I have to write a solution if I have a scheme to eval arbitrary code with fixed eraser length? ...

Comment: @user202729 [Yes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17412/existence-of-known-score-but-unknown-exact-code)

Comment: The quest for a unary answer begins...

Comment: @ouflak It seems to me the be a very significant departure from that challenge.  Checking if a string is the same thing repeated is much easier than checking if it has an eraser.  Have you maybe misread this question?

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score <sup><s>... 48</s> <s>29</s></sup>  20

```
+1,eval(bytes([57]))
```

A completely different approach from the last 2 versions (and also result in manageable generated program). Check out the revision history for some (possibly) interesting ideas.

---

Given an arbitrary Python program:

```
print(1)
```

it can be transformed, without changing the behavior:

```
exec("print(1)")
```

```
eval(rb'exec("print(1)")')
```

```
eval(bytes([101, 120, 101, 99, 40, 34, 112, 114, 105, 110, 116, 40, 49, 41]))
```

The number list is getting long, so I'll use a shorter list for demonstration. Note that only printable ASCII characters can appear in the string representation and the first character is `e`, so the first number is 101 and all numbers are at least 32.

```
eval(bytes([101, 32, 32]))
```

Rewrite the first number to `57+1+1+1+...+1+1+1`, the rest into `9+1+1+...+1`; then add some `,9` at the end of the list. This is always possible because of the conditions mentioned before, and the program's behavior is unchanged because **the byte `9` is `\t`, a whitespace character**.

```
eval(bytes([57+1+1+...+1, 9+1+1+...+1+1, 9+1+1+...+1, 9, 9,..., 9]))
```

The number of `,9` added must satisfy that **the total number of `9`s is equal to the number of `+1`**.

Then replace all the `9` with `eval(bytes([57])`, and prepend `+1,`.

```
+1,eval(bytes([57+1+1+...+1,eval(bytes([57])+1+1+...+1+1,eval(bytes([57])+1+1+...+1,eval(bytes([57]),eval(bytes([57]),...,eval(bytes([57])]))
```

Done! It's easy to see that this string has the eraser string `+1,eval(bytes([57])`.

---

It's trivial to see that there exists a Python snippet that solves the given problem.

```python
g=lambda s, e: not s or any(
	s[i:].startswith(e) and g(s[:i]+s[i+len(e):], e)
	for i in range(len(s)-len(e)+1))
f=lambda s: min((s[i:j] for j in range(len(s)+1) for i in range(j) if g(s, s[i:j])), key=len)
print(f(input()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHBboMwDD3XX2FxaSxop2k3pO5HEIewhmIGASWpNr6e2WWttgoHy89@ec8wL6mb/Nu6Xk6DHZuzxVigK9FPCSNOAa1fDOxixWV9jMmGFL84dcaRdM54MbEquc6lnw/OC1zWwifYtcJlZI/B@osz2ox02GbyVyJoH4IljuyNUY2@RiX2z0Rh4NONPSG3aqDAjUlU4KdbTsIg2O/3MAf2ybSG/XxNhkSTx3kKstgSQc7RfbPgOruC3h7TtW0LDC5eh6RK1cDeHeM8yFyGh3fMNhsKaz/LMrCNlWgkdMA28K9@FL/wX1RA99FNehTUDFOS51ZKBm5YQl4KSAa7qdlNSvILag1iRP5O4NnQZlcdRkN1Cbv7Z7htR/f1CGD9AQ)

Comment: 24B: `+eval('%c'*3%(32,49,32))` (will prove later)

Comment: 20B: `+1,eval(bytes([57]))` seems to work too.

Comment: That 20B solution can be ported to JavaScript -- but `String.fromCharCode` is significantly longer.

Comment: [`+1,eval(0+Buffer([57]))`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqEABP@1DXVSyxJzNAy0nUrT0lKLNKJNzWM1Nf9r/gcA) seem reasonable though

Comment: JavaScript's `Buffer` also have the property that values are automatically taken `%256`, but it doesn't seem to allow shortening the solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 23 bytes, score 23

Rather boring, as it doesn't have a non-trivial eraser.

```
{|~c₃↺↔At.l>0∧Akc↰}ᶠlᵒh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7qmLvlRU/Ojtl2P2qY4lujl2Bk86ljumJ38qG1D7cNtC3Iebp2U8f@/UmJiEhgp/Y8CAA) or [verify the other test cases](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7q6pi75UVPzo7Zdj9qmOJbo5dgZPOpY7pid/KhtQ@3DbQtyHm6dlFH7cOuE/6oK0UqZSZlABCSUYv9HKyUmJQJREhAp6ShhssHM1OSMfBAGMvNLgDAfqDMKAA) (split in two, so TIO doesn't time out.)

#### How it works

```
{|~c₃↺↔At.l>0∧Akc↰}ᶠlᵒh
{                 }ᶠ     Find all outputs for the implicit input, that …
 |                        either is itself or …
  ~c₃                     split into three groups in every possible way
                           [,,AAABBB],[,AA,AABB],[AAA,B,BB],[AA,AB,BB] etc. …
     ↺↔                    with the middle moved to the back [AA,BB,AB] …
       A                   assign to A
        t.                 the tail AB is the output of this predicate
          l>0              and its length is greater than 0.
             ∧Ak          Also, [AA,BB] …
                c          concatenated AABB …
                 ↰         used in a recursive call
                           has the same output as this predicate: AB.
                     lᵒh Order all possible erasers by length, take first
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 228 bytes, score 228

Naive solution I guess:

```
(r,d)=>{w=0;l=r.length;for(var i=0;i!=-1&&i<l;){i=r.indexOf(d,i);w=w||((i<0)?0:t(r.substr(0,i)+r.substr((i++)+d.length,l),d))}return !r?1:w}
f=a=>{n=a.length;for(p=1;p<=n;p++)for(i=0;i<=n-p;i++)if(t(a,b=a.substr(i,p)))return b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/dcoMgEIXv8xQmFxkYf6K3QZJH6DOAYrKNBQZJbCfx2e3aaibaDgsze/g4e3gXN9EUDqyPGwulch9GX9RX73lPXFRSfri3PGU1d0mt9MmfWWUcuQkXAMqw5nG23UJeM3oHZECX6vOtImUElLW8fTwIgTylx3TviUuaq2y8Iynehs@OQBjSsBz9o5riWNo55a9OB2t3zPZtt6q4wCiai9cYlmfM5lwziw6D8JMJhdiywRQq4omIJL4aZ0FkKaWjt@xWfWF0Y2qV1OZEKrIRUmBJrA2lQbDbBfEhEHK1wObUiD3F/@kJntF/YVWczbBn8CAsQeNxTdgEorTkQAIWHq9ZsV9y4vfvYjZ4EPpv)

Comment: Can't you replace `.substr(0,i)` with `slice(0,i)`? And remove `var `?